# Running long jobs in parallel and only after all jobs finishes to update the UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, parallel-processing

I'm building an `Android` app and I have some issues with the architecture - how to implement many calls on different threads.

I have 2 methods:

```
ConnectAndGetId() //takes 2-3 seconds
GetTokenID(ID)    //takes 2-3 seconds
```

First I need to call `ConnectAndGetId()` and then after getting a result `ID` to call `GetTokenID(ID)`.
After I get a `tokenID` I need to call 4 methods and pass them `tokenID`:

```
getNames (tokenID) //takes 4 second
getPhones (tokenID) //takes 7 seconds
getIds(tokenID) //takes 2 seconds
getDetailObject(tokenID) //takes 5 seconds
```

The idea is to show the data **ONLY** after I have the result from the **ALL 4 methods**. There is no need to execute them one by one because It will take a lot of time (18 sec), I want to run them in parallel and in the end with all the data to update the `UI`.

I thought to do the next thing:
Start `AsyncTask` and call to `ConnectAndGetId`,in `onPostExecute()` start another `AsyncTask` and run there `GetTokenID(ID)`. after I run `GetTokenID(ID)` I'll return the
result to `UI` thread and with the returned data I'll start 4 new `threads`, that each thread will call one of the 4 methods. I can count the finished threads,and when I got all the 4 result I can update the `UI` with handler.

Is it the right approach ? maybe I should not create 4 threads for 4 methods? else to create one `handlerThread` and pass the 4 methods to his handler so the Thread will pool them - but it will be one by one.

Is that the correct idea or It can be done better?

Answer (score 1):

It's normal approach. But I would recommend you to use `Executor` but not create `Threads`. Sample:

```
public class TasksSample {
    public static void execute(){
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        executorService.submit(new Task("A"));
        executorService.submit(new Task("B"));
        executorService.submit(new Task("C"));
        executorService.submit(new Task("D"));
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("all tasks finished");
    }

    private static class Task implements Runnable{

        private String taskId;

        public Task(String taskId) {
            this.taskId = taskId;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("finished task: " + taskId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very good question indeed. I think your aproach is correct, but I wouldn't create the GetTokenID thread on the onPostExecute(). I think it's better to use a Listener to ensure that you got the result you need. On the next step I would also use a Listener that would call your 4 methods.

The question is: do you need the 4 methods to finish to update your UI? then you should use a Listener with a synchronized block that would only enter when your 4 methods have finished. You can use a method that checks that these methods have got their results and when the 4 have completed, update the UI.

In case you don't need the 4 methods to finish to update the UI I would just put a ProgressDialog in the UI and update it method-by-method. In the last one dismiss the ProgressDialog and unblock the UI.

I hope it helps you out bro, good luck with coding!

Comment: Can you give an code example of using Listener in this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

Regarding if running four threads is appropriate for your situation only you can judge. It increases the complexity of the program and requires multithread access protection and synchronization on relevant data. Also consider if parallel access can actually speed up your computation. Parallel access only speeds up if the limiting factor is single-thread computational speed, if the limit lies with data bandwidth you won't see any significant gain in speed.

To your problem of four threads complete to one UI update you can try using a [CyclicBarrier](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) to lock all threads until the last one finishes execution.

The following shows an example:

```
// Create a CyclicBarrier with 4 parties and a target action to update UI

CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(4, new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //Do your UI updates here (remember any direct UI must be on UI thread)
    } 
});

// Pass above CyclicBarrier to your four threads


// Skeleton of Runnable instance for each of the four threads.

Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // Run desired long-running method

        // getNames, getPhones, etc

        // Call await() from CyclicBarrier instance (exception handling not shown)

        barrier.await();
    }
};
```

With the above code each thread that finishes will block on the await method until the fourth thread calls `await()` in which all threads unblock and the last thread runs the runnable passed to the CyclicBarrier at the start.

Comment: I should check the 'CyclicBarrier', never heard about it. Why it requires multithread access protection and synchronization? I run on each Thread only one method to bring data from web service. You said parallel access only speeds up if the limiting factor is single-thread - what you mean by that? If I call them in parallel in 4 threads it will be slower then calling them all in one thread?

Comment: @Dima If you aren't modifying any shared variables between the four threads than synchronization isn't really needed but otherwise it can be very important. The crux to decide to multithread or not is to figure out the exact point of slowdown, is it a computational limit either on your end or the server's or a data bandwidth limit. If the request takes 4 ~ 7 seconds because the server is sending hoards of data such that your network is being saturated, paralleling your code won't help as each request will simply take 4 times as long since they're sharing the same bandwidth.

Comment: @Dima If however, the delay lies with the server's computation and the server's computational abilities are single threaded and accept multiple requests on different threads then you will experience a speed up. Keep in mind the server may end up simply queuing your four requests into a single threaded operation, defeating your whole system. The best way to test is to simply benchmark and see if you do experience a speedup but think about if its actually worth the trouble to implement such a system.